# Interchanging two programs inputs and outputs

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout, stdin

The title of my question is rather misleading, but i could not find a better title for it.

The rephrased title is "I want Program x's output to be Program y's input and Program y's output to be Program x's input. Program x will start by giving output, while program y will start by accepting input."

```
Program x
        stdout --> <Program y>stdin
        stdin  --> <Program y>stdout
```

Any help?

Comment: Will it be a recursive call then? Can you elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: It will be a recursive call, which will go on until program Y give an output or W or L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash):

```
mkfifo xy_pipe
./program_x < xy_pipe | ./program_y > xy_pipe
```

A regular pipe is used to connect x's stdout to y's stdin.

To connect y's stdout to x's stdin we create a second, named pipe using `mkfifo`. A named pipe is an explicit way to connect two processes the way `|` normally does. Whenever a process writes to a named pipe it blocks until another process reads from the pipe. Although `xy_pipe` appears to be a file, no data is actually written to disk.

Example:

```
$ cat program_x
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
read line && echo "program_x: read '$line'" >&2

$ cat program_y
#!/bin/bash
read line && echo "program_y: read '$line'" >&2
echo bar

$ mkfifo xy_pipe
$ ./program_x < xy_pipe | ./program_y > xy_pipe
program_y: read 'foo'
program_x: read 'bar'
```

Don't forget to delete `xy_pipe` when you're done!

```
$ rm xy_pipe
```

If you want to see both programs' output on screen you can do that by adding `tee` to the mix.

```
$ mkfifo xy_pipe
$ ./program_x < xy_pipe | tee /dev/stderr | ./program_y | tee xy_pipe
foo
program_x says: foo
bar
program_y says: bar
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it actually does? It will help us a lot. Thank!

Comment: how to delete `xy_pipe` ?

Comment: You delete it by last line in the answer

Comment: I'd also like the 2 programs outputs on the screen. It does not happen